# MySql - Adding strings to column values from other column within the same table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have table which include 2 column: title and param, the values are like the following:

-title: Teaching

-params:

```
{   "ufield926":"34",
    "ufield927":"Sud",
    "ufield928":"Ara",
    "ufield929":"Mecca",
    "ufield930":"1\/1\/1983",
    "ufield933":"011",
    "ufield934":"Mub",
    "ufield943":"SU\/HI\/14",
    "ufield944":"Average",
    "ufield946":"Female"
}
```

I want to extract the code after "ufield943": which is SU/HI/14 only and concatenate it with the value in title column to be like the following:

--> Teaching (SU/HI/14)

Here is the query I tryingI have tried:

```
update tbl set title = CONCAT_WS(title,' ', '(' , (select *, substring( params, locate('ufield943', params) + 12, locate('ufield944', params) - locate('ufield943', params) - 15 )),')') from tbl;
```

I get the following error "ERR_PARSE_ERROR" every time I run the code.

Comment: Now maybe you see why comma delimited lists are such a bad idea in a database column

Comment: I think you could use a script like php to do that (if you have a lot of rows)

Comment: The real question is why you try to parse/extract from JSON data without using the native JSON functions which MySQL supports

Comment: Actually I have to make this update from phpmyadmin, that's why I am using mysql not php. Is there any ideas how to make the query work ?

Answer (score 1):

Export the table row/s to a csv, upload to google sheets and use the tool 'split text to column' and cleanup the csv.

Import the CSV back to the mysql table.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I agree, the OP should fix the data once.